# Google maps API - Direction without A and B markers / with waypoints marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

In google maps API, I show a direction.
I would like to delete the start and end markers (A and B) without deleting waypoints markers.

I know the "suppressMarkers" option but it suppresses waypoint markers.

My direction is draggable so it's not easy to make my own waypoints markers.

Could you please help me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Suppress the markers and then manually add markers for just the waypoints:

```
var my_renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: false});

for (waypoint in list_of_waypoints)
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: waypoint_location});
    marker.setMap(your_map);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I am not sure I understand. I create my_renderer with the option suppressMarkers:false, then I display the route using my_renderer.setDirections(response).

Where should I put your code ?

Thank you.

Comment: The best way to do it, would be to use suppressMarkers: true, then manually create and add the waypoint markers only. I'll update my code snippet to illustrate.

Comment: Yes but it will not fully replace a waypoint marker : if you drag it, the route will not dynamically follow. (my direction is draggable)

Comment: Yes, you can drag the marker but the direction polyline will not follow dynamically. How to "link" the marker to the polyline ?

Comment: I don't know the code for this offhand, but something along the vein of adding an event listener that listens for your marker being moved/dragged, and when that happens call a function that re-calculates the directions with an updated list of waypoints (that includes the marker's new location).

Comment: Ok. It seems quite complex. I thought I could find something simpler... Thank you.